# How to compare the result of two querys, or using one as a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that checks for the first registry that meet the conditions, the most important one being OK inside one of the columns with a json.

```
where p.metadata @> '{"state":"OK"}'
and 1=1
and ip.id = 62
and l.insurance_payment_id = 62
and (p.created_at::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Santiago' BETWEEN '2022-06-22 00:00:00-04'::timestamptz AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59-04'::timestamptz)
and op.id = 9
order by ps asc, p.created_at asc
limit 1
```

Now if a register comes in, I need to check for a foreign key id and see if it has enter  **for the first time** or not, using this query as a sub query to compare the results, how can I do that? I'm using postgresql.

EDIT: I forgot to add this:

```
where
  1=1
  AND ip.id=62
  AND l.insurance_payment_id=62
  AND (p.created_at::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Santiago' BETWEEN '2022-06-22 00:00:00-04'::timestamptz AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59-04'::timestamptz 
        AND op.id = 9) 
  /*AND no previous registries with state OK before*/
  and ps.metadata->>'state' = 'OK') as foo
```

This is where I shoud add the query, inside the commented line. I have the query that searches for the first registry ok to meet those conditions if there is one.

Comment: Join both queries and compare them, or use a subquery it doesn't matter performance  wise

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can boil down the condition of `no previous entries with state OK` into a query, you can limit your first query with the `EXISTS` clause.

Assume your condition is:

```
SELECT id
FROM other_tables
WHERE state='OK'
```

Then you can modify your first query like so,

```
where
  1=1
  AND ip.id=62
  AND l.insurance_payment_id=62
  AND (p.created_at::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Santiago' BETWEEN '2022-06-22 00:00:00-04'::timestamptz AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59-04'::timestamptz 
        AND op.id = 9) 
  AND EXISTS
      (SELECT id
       FROM other_tables
       WHERE state='OK'
        and id = ip.id)
```

`EXISTS` acts sort of like a True/False, so you don't actually have to SELECT anything (notice I did SELECT 1) and the join to your data takes place inside the WHERE clause inside `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this approach and it worked, may be good to share it

```
where
  1=1
  AND ip.id=62
  AND l.insurance_payment_id=62
  AND ((select p2.created_at from qppayment.payment p2 
        where p2.metadata @> '{"state":"OK"}'
        and p2.product_subscription_id = ps.id
        order by p2.created_at asc limit 1)::timestamptz at time zone 'America/Santiago'
    BETWEEN '2022-06-22 00:00:00-04'::timestamptz AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59-04'::timestamptz 
    and op.id = 9)
  and ps.metadata->>'state' = 'OK') as foo
```